# What are the Pros and Cons of Using Two Handed Weapons as a Monk?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monks and the effectiveness of 2-handed weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66792/monks-and-the-effectiveness-of-2-handed-weapons)

I am leveling as a monk on Diablo 3, so far, i've managed to use Daibos as weapons (i've found a rare one).

My question is : should i use 2x fists instead of a Daibo ? What are the advantages of one over another.

Also, Lets say my Daibo does 40.0 damage, will i do more damage with 2x Fists doing 40.0 damage each ? Are the skill damage based on Weapons SUM or just the weapon in the main hand ?

There are some skills for example, that does 110% weapon damage, but what happens if i am dual wielding ? How does it works ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that.