# Monk skills suited for CC and tanking

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a monk tank effectively for a group?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68529/how-can-a-monk-tank-effectively-for-a-group)

When playing with my friends (who play ranged classes), I mostly end up tanking / crowd controlling with my monk. Are there any specific skills (and runes) that could help me do this?

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to this question: [How can a monk tank effectively for a group?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68529/8462)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Rachel's comment linking to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68529/8462) is a far better answer, this question is almost a duplicate of that one except for the CC part.

---

I can mention some skills to **avoid** based on whether you are grouping with classes that like AoE damage - specifically, those that cause knockback and tend to scatter the enemies (some runes of `Lashing Kick` for e.g.). Also for these same AoE fans, a judicious use of `Cyclone` to group enemies for handy execution can be useful.

When you need to focus on a single target like a boss or elite champion; `Exploding Palm` runed with `The Flesh Is Weak` can help, I think it also stacks with the Demon Hunter's `Marked For Death` skill.

Witch doctors are also a ranged class, if your friends play a summoner style WD then depending on the area having `Mantra of Retribution` or Healing could be a great support (Haven't reached there, but maybe Retribution in Hell/Inferno works well with disposable fodder?)

Also, having a high damage teleporting attack skill, e.g. `Seven Sided Strike` with `Sudden Assault` can be a great situational rescue tool.

Comment: +1 for `Cyclone`+`Implosion` and `Crippling Wave`+`Mangle`

Comment: Crippling Wave works very well, but I didn't mention it as it is unrelated to the question

Comment: Yeah, it's just one of the best combo's I've found so far. Agreed though, more for a PBAoE build

Comment: Crippling Wave with concussion in Hell+ is great. Before that, extra damage is generally more useful for CC.

Comment: Crippling Wave adds a snare, which is a kind of CC - it's very relevant, and in Inferno, extra damage alone can't save you.

Comment: `Blinding Flash` blinds, and `Breath of Heaven` has a rune that does an AOE fear.  Both of these are great monk CC.

Answer (score 2):

If your not in inferno, listen to any of these guys, but once you hit inferno you better have a decent set of resist gear and you'll need to change up your skills.  Honestly I had  very little trouble getting to 60 with terrible equipment and skills, it wasn't until I hit 60 that I started to do research and theory crafting.  I actually posted my build/guide on the link that Rachel posted yesterday, after looking at this site and getting very frustrated with it's lack of an end game monk guide.  I'm sure everyone else's guides will help you in hell in one way or another, but once you get to inferno your party will need a serious tank.

My builds devoted to all 4 defensive skills, mantra that gives evasion and armor, and deadly reach with the armor rune for my primary.  This keeps me up and able to tank most of the minions for my group.  It seems that a lot of the people posting on this topic plan on playing solo.  I don't at all, and don't expect to beat the game solo, so if you have the same play style, don't worry about the damage aspect of it.  I only put out 9.2k dps for inferno act1 and 2, but my buddies I group up with put out 46K dps, but they cant take a hit at all...  Independently we can't do anything, but as a group we roll through act 1 and beginning of act 2inferno, and none of has any great gear...

I don't know, I just get frustrated when I see all these "tank" builds that focus more on damage and avoidance to win fights quickly. But to each his own, hopefully this helps...