# Which is more important as a Monk, Dodge% or Block%?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I be an effective tanking Monk without a Shield at higher difficulty levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68519/can-i-be-an-effective-tanking-monk-without-a-shield-at-higher-difficulty-levels)

Currently I am a [level 39 Monk](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/monk#beXVih!cXd!bZbaZa) in the middle of Act II on Nightmare. My items and build right now are fine, but I'm starting to notice enemies getting more difficult. As of right now I run with two one-handed weapons (to proc The Guardian's Path passive skill) and the Mantra of Evasion to boost my dodge chance up to around 45%.

My dilemma is this; a friend of mine that has been playing since launch advised that I pick up a shield instead of the second weapon. This would free up a passive slot (to replace The Guardian's Path), give me more armor, and give me a chance to block...but at the cost of DPS (loss of a weapon) and dodge% (loss of The Guardian's Path proc). Dodge blocks **all** oncoming damage for that attack whereas blocking only removes X amount of damage. When I brought this up, he just told me to 'Do it and see what happens'.

So. As I move towards the Hell and Inferno difficulties, would it be worth dropping a weapon for a shield?

Comment: both if you can get it

Comment: Added a bit to my question to clarify.
Replacing the weapon with a shield loses 15% dodge chance because of how The Guardian's Path works.

Comment: in that case then this is what you are looking for: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68519/can-i-be-an-effective-tanking-monk-without-a-shield-at-higher-difficulty-levels/74314#74314

Comment: Interesting. Defensively, that argument definitely makes sense. I had thought that shields only gave up to about 15% block chance! In that case, does playing with a shield lower your DPS to the point where you become ineffective in solo Inferno?

Comment: that highly depends on your weapons and equipment.  My monk has about 1200 dex and does about 15k dps, but I can pretty much tank most of A3 inferno.

Comment: Does [the answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68519/can-i-be-an-effective-tanking-monk-without-a-shield-at-higher-difficulty-levels/74314#74314) linked by yx answer your question? Your questions *seems* like a duplicate of it to me, but I'm honestly having some trouble trying to figure exactly what you're asking (your question is a little unclear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with a DH build eventually the benefits of a shield start to outweigh the benefits of a second weapon.

As nice as it is to deal damage and clear enemies more quickly, heck sometimes it feels essential, having low armor, resists and other goodies common on a shield will get you killed from most of the AOE affixes.

So the debate between dodge and block % might seem very important, I would argue it's not, but having a decent level of both is even more effective than a high roll of one or the other.

I've done too much math tonight to demonstrate it, but in essence if you fail the dodge check you can now take a chance on the block check.  It's combinatorially more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a shield, since it also gives you a significant boost to armour.  It really depends on your style of play and what skills you are using though.